# Ios 5 crashes during [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

The issue occurs in

```
while (!self.complete && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]])
{

}
```

App crashs with signal

```
-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8577710
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the `-bytes` message to an instance of `NSString`. You probably mean to send it to an instance of `NSData`. As you didn't show that part of the code, it's hard to tell what you'd do to fix it.

Comment: NSURL *dst = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url stringByAppendingString:self.operation]];
    [r setURL:dst];
 [r setValue:dst.host forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [r setHTTPBody:self.request];
    [r setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", len] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kRequestFactoryRequestStarted object:nil];
 self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:r delegate:self];

Comment: this issue occurs only IOS 5

Comment: Since the crash happens during the waiting period, it's more likely to be in your delegate methods than in the initialisation. Can you edit your question to show the delegate methods there? That's easier to read than putting them in a comment.

Comment: my delegate methods should not be called

Comment: In which case, then it will do no harm to put a `NSLog` message at the start and end of each delegate method, just to keep track of when they are not being called.